# How to read the content of a text file in an iOS tweak

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

inside an iOS tweak, I have a long text and store it in a text file at the same folder level with .xm file. Let's say I have a tweak project with a Tweak.xm file at the top level of the project, and another file called myFile.txt placed at the same folder level as Tweak.xm. How do I read the content of this txt file in the xm code?

I tried this Objective-C code but an error came up as the file path may not be correct.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@", error);
    NSLog(@"File Path: %@", filePath);
    // the log error is `Error reading file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 "The file name is invalid."`
} else {
    NSLog(@"File Content:\n%@", fileContent);

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a little redesign but it should work correctly for your purposes.

Example Code:

```
NSError *error = nil;

// Open the file and create it if it doesn't exist
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myFile.txt", documentsDirectory];
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];

if (fileHandle == nil) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
}

// Open the output stream
NSOutputStream *outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:YES];
[outputStream open];

// Open the input stream
NSInputStream *inputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:filePath];
[inputStream open];

// What you are writing
NSString *printString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello Logos\n"];

// Write to file
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
NSData *contentData = [printString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[outputStream write:contentData.bytes maxLength:contentData.length];

// Read from file
size_t fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:&error] fileSize];
if(error) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@", error);
    return;
}
NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:fileSize];
size_t result = [inputStream read:(uint8_t *)data.bytes maxLength:fileSize];
if(result != fileSize) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to read %zu bytes, only read %zu!", fileSize, result);
}
NSLog(@"%@: contains:\n%@", filePath, [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Test run:

```
❯ xcrun clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot $(xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path) -O3 -DNDEBUG test.m -o test -framework Foundation

/var/folders/x2/gjkg0qk92j92svxfk1x1cn100000gn/T
❯ rm ~/Documents/myFile.txt
rm: cannot remove '/Users/cryptic/Documents/myFile.txt': No such file or directory

/var/folders/x2/gjkg0qk92j92svxfk1x1cn100000gn/T
❯ ./test
2023-08-27 19:48:23.654 test[2318:1592365] /Users/cryptic/Documents/myFile.txt: contains:
Hello Logos

/var/folders/x2/gjkg0qk92j92svxfk1x1cn100000gn/T
❯ ./test
2023-08-27 19:48:24.381 test[2361:1592410] /Users/cryptic/Documents/myFile.txt: contains:
Hello Logos
Hello Logos

/var/folders/x2/gjkg0qk92j92svxfk1x1cn100000gn/T
❯ ./test
2023-08-27 19:48:25.304 test[2387:1592456] /Users/cryptic/Documents/myFile.txt: contains:
Hello Logos
Hello Logos
Hello Logos

/var/folders/x2/gjkg0qk92j92svxfk1x1cn100000gn/T
❯
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detail code @Cryptic. I tried your code and found out that although "myFile.txt" is already placed in the same folder level as Tweak.xm file, the log print nothing on the first injection to the app and a blank "myFile.txt" file was created in the app document. Anyway it did give me an other solution, which is to manually go to the app document directory in Filza and edit the newly created blank "myFile.txt" myself. I just wondering if there are any way to directly get the text content from the tweak and not having to create and edit a text file the doc directory